# NullInjectorError: No provider for MatBottomSheetRef

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

[In this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-baseline2-country-code-select?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial.module.ts) I'm getting the following error (Even though the `MatBottomSheetModule` is imported):

```
        ERROR
        Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CountryCodeSelectComponent -> MatBottomSheetRef]:
        StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CountryCodeSelectComponent -> MatBottomSheetRef]:
        NullInjectorError: No provider for MatBottomSheetRef!
```

Thoughts?

### Angular / Components Feature Request

If you agrre you can vote for this.  I requested making the use case symmetrical WRT how we make use of other similar Angular components / services.

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17011

Comment: I actually injected MatBottomSheet instead of MatBottomSheetRef and called the dismiss() method on MatBottomSheet. It worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need providers for Bottom Sheet which you were missing.

Make these changes to **material.module.ts**

```js
import {MatBottomSheetRef, MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';

@NgModule({
  exports: [...]
  providers: [
    { provide: MatBottomSheetRef, useValue: {} },
    { provide: MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA, useValue: {} }
  ],
})
```

This is the recommended approach for Treeshaking for webpack for more performant and minimized bundles:

In file: **country-code-select.component.ts**

```js
// Removed -1
// import { MatBottomSheetRef } from '@angular/material'; 


//Added +1
import { MatBottomSheetRef} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
```

The Stackblitz for your reference

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-baseline2-country-code-select-6hisdk

And you are set. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for pointing all this out! I put in a feature request to make the use case symmetrical WRT to the rest of angular:https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17011

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer works but you will get the `this._bottomSheet.open is not a function` error, simplest solution will be to:

`import {MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';` in your component module or app module, and at it to your imports

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    ...,
  ],
  declarations: [...],
})
```